# How to print $_

Tags: perl

How can I print $_ outside using grep? I want to print the data inside `%try_1` if it match with `%try`
.........

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::Autotie 'Tie::IxHash';

tie my %try, 'Tie::IxHash';
$try{STRONG}{ALLIES}='A';
$try{AGILE}{BOBBY}='B';
$try{AGILE}{HOBBY}='B';
$try{SMART}{CAKRA}='C';
$try{SMART}{PHONE}='C';
$try{SMART}{PEOPLE}='C';
my %try_1;
$try_1{STRONGER}='A';
$try_1{AGILER}='B';
$try_1{SMARTER}='C';

foreach my $temp_0 (keys %try)
{
    print "\n".$_."\n" if (grep {$_ =~ /$temp_0/i} (keys %try_1));
 }
```

Comment: @ikegami My assumption was that he was looking for keys in `%try_1` that would be matched by a key in `%try`. Like `STRONGER` in `%try_1` is matched by `STRONG` in `%try`.

Comment: @ChrisCharley, Oops, yeah. Deleted my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Change:

```
print "\n".$_."\n" if (grep {$_ =~ /\Q$temp_0/i} (keys %try_1));
```

To:

```
print "\n".$_."\n" for grep {/\Q$temp_0/i} keys %try_1;
```

The `\Q` handles any special character `$temp_0` might contain.